# when using session tokens, should the authority be a PDA, what is the reasoning behind this?

Tags: magicblock, session-token, gum

In the examples that I have seen, for example from the [lumberjack game](https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples/blob/7bf574b105629d1cfab7ec30e8a26768143affb4/lumberjack/program/programs/lumberjack/src/instructions/chop_tree.rs#L31C2-L39C1), the authority seems to always seems to be from a PDA, what is the main reasoning behind this.

```
#[session(
        // The ephemeral key pair signing the transaction
        signer = signer,
        // The authority of the user account which must have created the session
        authority = player.authority.key()
    )]
    // Session Tokens are passed as optional accounts
    pub session_token: Option<Account<'info, SessionToken>>,
```

Also, is it possible to use it when the PDA isn't yet initialized